# lameAMC wont install (for dxtory)

Tags: windows-8, mp3, lame

when i do exactly as the instructions do it opens a 'copy error' window saying

Setup cannot copy the file LameACM.acm

Ensure that the location specified below is correct, or change it and insert 'Lame MP3 Install Disk' in the drive you specify.

copy files from:
C:\lame

iv tried every possible combination of the items in the folder being named Lame MP3 Install Disk but nothing is working so if anyone can help that would be awesome and if you need anymore infromation about anything(like system specs or something ask)  also i have window 8.1

Answer (score 0):

on windows 8, go to the start menu and hit c, find cmd prompt and right click it and run as administrator

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but answering since it's the only result of a Google search.

Not a problem with Administrator/UAC (it doesn't even get this far if not elevated). This problem is from either the read-only flag or the security zone info added to the downloaded files.

Just go into the properties for each file, clear Read-only and check "Unblock" too.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this, in Windows 10, by opening properties for each file and checking the box "Unlock", next to attributes. It was something related to security as the file had been copied from another computer.

Comment: This is a comment not really an answer.  Also, the OP mentions Windows 8.1 NOT Windows 10.  Of more use would be why the issue is arising, like that file permissions were not being allowed or improperly set/interpreted on one or the other machine.